# PHP substring before and after specific character until space, comma ...?

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping, substring

I'm trying to scrape an email. Lets say I have a long string :

```
$str = "this is the email query@stackoverflow.com which you might want to scrape";
$needle_1 = "@";
$needle_2 = array("[ ]","[,]","["]");
```

I'd like to extract the email. I assume using the @ is the solution.
So basically, I need to get all the characters before and after @ till the space, comma or ".

**best trial is currently:**

```
$string = 'this is the email query@stackoverflow.com which you might want to scrape';
$template = "/[\w]+[@][\w]+[.][\w]+/";
preg_match_all($template, $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Can you show what you already have? And `array(" ",",""";` is not valid PHP

Comment: I edited the question ! Basically, i think that a strpos might help to get the length till needle_2 and then using a loop. But I can't figure out the application of it.

Comment: It won't work in every case `[\w\.]+@[\w\.]+`, and it won't work if there is in some other place `@`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it looks better

```
  $string = 'this is the email query@stackoverflow.com which you might want to scrap';
  $template = "/[\w]+[@][\w]+[.][\w]+/";
  preg_match_all($template, $string, $matches);
  var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a regex for that :

```
<?php 
    $str = "this is the email query@stackoverflow.com which you might want to scrap";
    $pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
    var_dump($matches[0]);
?>
```